# "in goblin eyes" vs "in a goblin's eyes"

Tags: phrase-usage

> All goblin-made objects are, **in goblin eyes**, rightfully theirs.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I'm wondering what would be the difference between "in goblin eyes" and "in a goblin's eyes" in the context. Are they the same? Can it also be *in goblins' eyes*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your examples

> **in a goblin's eye** *(singular)*
>   **in goblins' eyes** *(plural)*

means something that is ***literally*** **in** an eye

However,

> **in goblin eyes**

is idiomatic and means

> from the ***perspective*** of a goblin (any goblin)

the same as

> in **dog** years

means

> the length of a year as measured by a dog

Comment: Originally, I thought of the phrase "in your eyes", which  uses the possessive 'your'. That's why I thought "in goblins' eyes" might have the similar meaning.

Comment: Re: [dog years](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dog%20years), there are seven dog years for every calendar year. e.g. 25 years = 175 dog years.